# Removing only a named volume when running docker compose down

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a compose file with three volumes.

```
...
volumes:
  db-data-volume:
  proxy_data:
  proxy_config:
  web-assets:
...
```

When I stop and remove the containers (`docker compose down`) I also need to destroy ONLY the `web-assets` volume.

I understand the command `docker compose down -v` removes named volumes declared in the “volumes” section of the Compose file. But, is it possible to remove just a specific volume?

If so, is there a way to make it default when I run the `down` command?

Comment: Why that one volume and not the others?  (Are you trying to use it to publish files from one container to another, and if so, would it be cleaner to `COPY` the files in your Dockerfile?)

Comment: I use that volume to share files between containers. The files need to be recreated at every start.

Comment: How does your container populate the volume?  Or are you relying on Docker copying files into the volume for you on startup?  (I'd avoid that path, as something extremely specific to Docker named volumes, and something that can cause changes in your images to be hidden with the old volume content.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running docker on linux you could try to run your volume in tmpfs mode. Then the volume will be saved in memory and not persisted on your harddrive.

Not sure if its also running on other OS. Tmpfs mounts are declared to only run on linux. Maybe volumes in tmpfs mode also runs on other OS.

For that do:

```
volumes:
  db-data-volume:
  proxy_data:
  proxy_config:
  web-assets:
    driver_opts:
      type: tmpfs
      device: tmpfs
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From the Docker documentation "Limitations of tmpfs mounts

    Unlike volumes and bind mounts, you can’t share tmpfs mounts between containers."

Comment: Yes. But this is a volume running in tmpfs mode and not a tmpfs mount. I would give it a try.